# Undefined array with initialization oninit

Tags: angular

I have this snippet:

```
usersTempList=[];

ngOnInit() {
  this.obj = {user: JSON.parse(localStorage.userDetails),room:"Sala" + this.projectID, projectID: this.projectID};
  this.loggedUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.userDetails).UserID;
  this.roomList.push(this.obj.room);
  this.usersTempList=[];
  console.log("Initialized array")
  this.join(this.obj);
  ...
}

join(obj: any){
    this.socket.emit("join",obj,this.getOnline);
}

getOnline(err,msg){
  console.log(this.usersTempList);
  console.log("Printed array");
  this.usersTempList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg));
  console.log("qwerty",this.usersTempList);
}
```

Opening this component on the browser, neither `*ngFor` works (it isn't printing anything) and, the `console.log` of the first line of `getOnline` always prints `undefined`. Also, even that the variable is updated in the subsequent lines, `*ngFor` still doesn't update the interface.

Does anyone have any clue about this?

Thanks!

Comment: Please share your HTML code, and first of all here,  getOnline is a function which is not returning anything.

Comment: could you also further specify the output you would want to see?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was solved, it happened because I couldn't access my array inside my scope, so I used an arrow function and it worked, usersTempList wasn't undefined anymore..

```
join(obj: any){
  this.socket.emit("join",obj, (err,msg) => {      
        this.usersTempList=JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(msg))
    });
}
```

Thank you all!